# How to include Null values in Join

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

I am working on an assignment which needs me to generate a list of films showing name and year and actor number that have the word "JEDI" in the title. In the actor number column only show actor number 3 if the movie has actor 3 in them, otherwise show null. Order by film title.

My current code is as follows:

```
select film_actor.film_id, title, actor_id from film_actor
left join film
on film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
where actor_id in (select actor_id from film_actor where actor_id = "3")
and title like "%JEDI%"
group by film_id
order by title
```

This outputs only the result that matches where actor_id = "3", but it doesn't show the two films where "JEDI" is in the title but actor_id is not 3.
[This image shows the desired result on the right, and my result on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5MVk.png)

What can I change in my code to get to the desired result?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since you're joining `film` to `film_actor`, you'll get all the possible results from `film_actor`, and `NULL` if there isn't any corresponding `film` for that actor. You're either looking for a `RIGHT` join, or you want to switch those two tables in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `film` the parent table, and `actor` the table you left join with, since that's the one that may not have a matching element (you could also use `RIGHT JOIN`, but that's less common).

And then you need to put the criteria of the `actor` table into the `ON` condition, not `WHERE`.

```
SELECT film.film_id, film.title, film_actor.actor_id
FROM film
LEFT JOIN film_actor
ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id AND film_actor.actor_id = 3
WHERE title LIKE '%JEDI%'
ORDER BY title
```

There's no need for `GROUP BY` here.

Answer (score 0):

Your left join is backwards for your purpose, since you want all matching films but only the actor when there is one:

```
select film.film_id, title, actor_id
from film
left join film on film.film_id = film_actor.film_id and film_actor.actor_id = "3"
where title like "%JEDI%"
order by title
```

No group by is necessary if there is at most one actor_id 3 per film

Comment: fixed column select to have the film id that always exists